# orphan removal is not working properly

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an one-to-many collection annotated as following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderColumn(name ="index")
    private List<Preference> preferences;
}
```

Preference entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "preferences")
public class Preference {
    // id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;
    private Integer index;
}
```

I try to remove an element from the list like this:

```
public void removePreference(Preference preference) {
    preferences.remove(preference);
    preference.setStudent(null);
}
```

The above code is not working, the entity is not removed from the table. How can i achieve this?

Comment: what is `preferences`?

Comment: added more info in the question

Comment: I mean `preferences.remove(preference);`

Comment: A collection of Preference objects, with orphanRemoval set true..

Comment: Is the other class `Student` or `Students`?

Comment: It's the same, sorry, it was a mistake.

Comment: It seems like the `index` column name can cause problems. Which DB are you using? in the logs, do you have any "error in SQL syntax" message?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSql 9.4, i don't have any sql syntax errors. The method executes,  the student_id is set to null but the entity is not deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `Project` to `Preference` relationship is defined the same way that `Student` to `Preference` then your problem comes from the fact that your `Preference` entity is the child of two others entity.

When you remove it from the student's preference it is marked as an removed entity by Hibernate but as it is still referenced by the project Hibernate will re-manage it, as it is specified in the [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) for this use case. Check section 3.2.2 and 3.2.3 about persisting and removing.

To solve your case you can delete it from all sides or check if a `@ManyToMany` relationship between `Student` and `Project` with `Preference` as join table wouldn't suit better.